# yield return IEnumerator or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm new to C#, just a question on yield keyword which confuses me a lot.
It seems that yield  can return an IEnumerator  and IEnumerable

```
//case 1
static IEnumerator YieldReturn()
{
   yield return 1;
   yield return 2;
   yield return 3;
}
```

and

```
//case 2
static IEnumerable YieldReturn()
{
   yield return 1;
   yield return 2;
   yield return 3;
}
```

how come one thing can return two different return types?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: You can think about it as `YieldReturn` essentially returns `IEnumerable`, but as this interface has `GetEnumerator` method `YieldReturn` can also be casted to `IEnumerator`

Answer (score 3):

A method using `yield` is rebuilt by the compiler. It creates a state machine with a whole new compiler-generated class.

This state-machine-class is an `IEnumerator` as well as an `IEnumerable` whose `GetEnumerator` method returns itself.

So depending on how you declare your method, the compiler emits code that either returns the `IEnumerable` or an already initialized `IEnumerator`.

As always, [Jon Skeet](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/IteratorBlockImplementation) has a good article about what happens under the hood with the `yield` keyword.